# Is there an un-bypassable way to protect my bios settings?

Tags: mac, boot, bios, passwords, cmos

Is there a way to protect my bios settings beyond any sort of method of bypassing? I just set a long bios password but if it as easy as merely removing the CMOS battery to bypass the password, what should I do? To be more specific, my friend is planning on having my computer boot MacOS instead of Windows without me noticing (as a joke). What can I do to keep this from happening?

Comment: tell him not to?

Comment: Don't give him access to your computer.

Answer (score 4):

**Rule 1: Physical access is Root Access. Period.**

In general, if a luggage padlock is not sufficient, then you put it in a locked room. if that's insufficient, you add a retinal scanner. if that''s still not  sufficient, guards with guns....

Comment: ... sharks with laser beams?